# Animating drawable inside imagebutton (using icondrawable)

Tags: android, animationdrawable

I am looking to animate a drawable inside imagebutton. I have created a drawable using https://github.com/JoanZapata/android-iconify/

```
Drawable d= new IconDrawable(this, MaterialIcons.md_phone_locked).colorRes(R.color.white_smoke).actionBarSize();
        takeBtn.setImageDrawable(d);
```

I would like to animate (pulsate infinite) to the icondrawable inside the imagebutton. I can animate the whole button, but am looking to animate just the drawable inside the button

Any suggestions are highly appreciated

Thanks